# Why are Gatorbacks so expensive?

Tags: playing-cards

David Blaine's Gaterbacks sell easily at around the £20 mark. However, as far as I know, they aren't marked, they don't come with any gaff cards and other than the foil backs they aren't custom or even on a rare card-stock.

As a fairly new magician, I struggle to understand why such playing cards are as expensive as they are! Fontaine's are very limited, hence their price... are gaterbacks also very limited? What's so special about them?

Comment: I noticed there wasn't a forum for magic/ cardistry as well as a lack of tags relating to such things. Dear MODS if you must mark this as off topic, please tell me where I can post such a question.

Comment: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/v/veblen-good.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply because it is a name brand that focuses on quality. Looking at the official site they put an emphasis on quality and combine that with a very big and popular name brand you get a higher price.

Having to license the David Blaine name and brand is most likely very expensive and is why you see a higher price on many name brand products.

Comment: Damn, I hate having to pay for a brand name. Why can't we have cool cards that cost the same as bikes?? They basically cost the same to produce. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @117Halo What do you mean by "cool cards"?  If you mean that you want to have the sar quality as bikes but in many different designs, they definitely do not cost the same.  Material is the same cost per deck but lower print runs and multiple die changes increases the manufacturing cost exponentially.